# Registro de actividad PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Saludos a todos, tengo una pequeña tabla donde todos pueden consultar, editar e insertar y quiero saber quien ha hecho algun movimiento pero sin usar login mas bien saber por medio del nombre de la pc o usuario de windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.4+ te da el nombre de la pc, puedes ingresarlo en la base de datos.

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

Comment: soy novato en esto podrias darme un poco mas de luz? @omar Montoya

Comment: Claro, habría que hacer otra columna en la base de datos para saber quien fue el que creó/editó la entrada. 

`$usuario = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo hice pero en otra tabla que le puse log, quiero puntuar tu respuesta pero no me deja xoxo